# Building and debugging static library in Xcode using external build system

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I'm trying to embed a set of static libraries that are made by an external build system into a project. I can get the external build system to build the libraries just fine in Xcode and I can use them in another project.

However, the project I am compiling (ffmpeg) produces several static libraries and I'm not clear at all how I should set this up in Xcode such that it can be referenced by another project and when I change the ffmpeg source it is rebuilt and can be debugged.  Any pointers?